# Vue CLI Run separate CSS build?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-cli

I'm trying to run a completely separate css/sass build to a specific file.

So I have a folder in my src like:

```
/src
   /sass
      ./index.sass
      ./btn.sass
      ./etc.sass
```

I'm trying to get it to output to a specific file like "build.css" or whatever which would just end up in the default build directory of "dist" as "dist/build.css".

Been trying to play with vue.config.js and chainWebpack but totally lost here.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the sass files compiled into a single css? Or you want to compile just one of many sass files?

Comment: @match so ya, all the sass files compiled into a single css. I guess I should have clarified that better. I'm thinking it will be one index.css with a bunch of includes inside so really just `/src/sass/index.sass` to a specific output css file.

Comment: To clarify, you want this build separate from the regular app build (and in addition to that's build's CSS output)?

Comment: @tony19 yep, I know it sounds a bit weird and should probably be a separate build/codebase but just trying to do a bit of a shortcut here as I need the css in multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a Webpack `entry` that points to the Sass file you want to bundle (using [`configureWebpack.entry`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)):

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ⋮
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      app: './src/main.js',
      extCss: './src/sass/index.sass', 
    },
  },
})
```

This has a downside as it also generates a `.js` file that is effectively a no-op. You'd have to delete that manually as a cleanup step:

```sh
dist/css/app.css
dist/css/extCss.css           # CSS bundle of Sass output
dist/js/app.js
dist/js/chunk-vendors.js
dist/js/extCss.js             # no-op file (delete me)
```

Also delete the `<script src="/js/extCss.js"></script>` from  `dist/index.html`.